Why did the view failed to be created when using `create view` command in Apache IoTDB?
I would like to ask why did I fail to create the view using the sql statement example on the official website? The error reported View is not supported. My statements executed in step order are:
1.CREATE TIMESERIES root.test.device.s01 WITH DATATYPE=DOUBLE, ENCODING=RLE;
2.insert into root.test.device(timestamp,s01) values( 2021-01-01T08:00:00.019+08:00,10.30);
3.select s01 from root.test.device;
4.CREATE VIEW root.view.device.status AS SELECT s01  FROM root.test.device.

If you are using open source version of Apache IoTDB, then this error happen may because it does not includes the view function. View function can only be executed in the enterprise version.
